# Scrollbars or grey bars on TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting weird bars on my TextView, I am assuming these are scroll bars (?)

It does not happen on all devices, but I sometimes saw them on my testing devices (and sometimes not) and now saw them again in my pre launch report.

Does anyone know what the cause could be or how I can hide them?

[image: TextView with Scrollbar]

This is the code of one of the TextViews

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/defaultText"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView12"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Since I do not get it on my own devices right now, I cannot tell if explicitly setting "scrollable" to false will change anything, but I am assuming for TextViews this is the default value.

Answer (score 1):

The `TextView` is set to a fixed height, you can change it to:

```xml
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Which will automatically scale the height to fit the text content, preventing scrollbars from appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to add scrollbars in your textview but if you willing to do this then

just add

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

in xml layout.

and then

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

in your code.

now it will!